# Enable button click only after the page is loaded

Tags: android, button

I have a page which contains a listview alone. Upon clicking a row in the list, the next page is loaded. This next page contains a set of buttons. Upon clicking a row in the list, the loading of the next page may take sometime. So if someone is continuously clicking the row then at some point of time, the second page comes and the buttons inside that gets clicked, which I dont require. How can I prevent this clicking of buttons? Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your activities are taking longer than a couple hundred milliseconds to load, you may want to think about offloading some of your logic into a separate thread, or simplifying your layout.  You may get an ANR if you do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) concept to load data for next activity, do as follow:

1. set setEnabled(false) to all buttons inside the onPreExecute() method.
2. do all the background task inside the doInBackground() method.
3. and now again setEnabled(true) to all the buttons so that it become enabled and user can click on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to false click event and true while you want to use

like this::

```
button1.setClickable(false);
```

and when you want to enable just write

```
button1.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that your activities shouldn't take that long to load initially, you could just set a boolean when `startActivity()` is called to start the new activity.  Then check that boolean if the user clicks anything else before the next activity is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.readyState==complete) //NB this property is not supported by firefox
{
//Activate buttons
}
```